# Probability of $\max_i \{X_i\} = X_0$ where $X_i$ are iid binomial

Tags: probability, random-walk, binomial-distribution

We have $M$ Binomial random variables, where $X_0 \sim $ Bin$(n,p)$ and $X_i \sim $ Bin$(n,1/2)$.

Suppose $p > 1/2$. I'm interested in the probability that $\mathbb{P}(\max \{X_1,\dots,X_M\} \geq X_0)$. Is this tractable?

If not, is it tightly boundable/approximable? If this is a very difficult question, I'd accept a reference providing some insight on the problem as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P( \max \{X_1,...,X_M \} \geq X_0)=P(X_i \geq X_0$ for some i) = $1-P( \text{each }X_i < X_0)$.

Now $P( \text{each }X_i < X_0)=\sum_{k=0}^n P(\text{each }X_i<X_0 \vert X_0=k) \cdot P(X_0 =k)$ =$\sum_{k=0}^n P( \text{each } X_i<k \text{ and } X_0=k)$ = $\sum_{k=1}^n \big[ P(X_1<k) \big]^M \cdot P(X_0=k)$.  Note the k=0 term is 0.

Comment: $X_0$ isn't given though.

Comment: The events $\{X_i<X_0\}$ are not mutually independent, since $X_0$ appears in each of them. You need to condition on the value of $X_0$.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist sorry for misreading your question, let me make an edit right now

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of $\{X_i\}_{i\in\{1;M\}}$ will be at least as great as $X_0$ when it is not that all values are less than $X_0$.   (Employ the rule of complements.)   Assuming that $X_0$ is *also* independent of the iid variables then:
$$\begin{align}
 \mathsf P\left(\max_{i=1}^M\{X_i\} \geqslant X_0\right) =&~ 1-\sum_{k=1}^n\mathsf P(X_0=k)\mathsf P\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^M X_i<k\Big)
\\ =&~ 1- 2^{-nM} \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\left(\sum_{h=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{h}\right)^M
\end{align}$$